# Using Pytorch Dataloader with Probability Distribution

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

TL;DR: I want to use `DataLoader` to take a **weighted** random sample of the available rows. How do?

---

I've put together some python code that fits a certain kind of input-driven dynamical system to data using batched gradient descent over the parameters that define the model. I have the following snippet of Python code that gets the job done using Pytorch.

```
k_trn = self.linear.k_gen(in_trn,t)
u_trn = torch.tensor(in_trn.T)
x_trn = torch.tensor(out_trn.T, dtype = torch.float)
data = TensorDataset(u_trn[:-1,:],k_trn[:-1,:],x_trn[1:,:])
loader = DataLoader(data, batch_size = 20, shuffle = True)
```

Data types:

- `u_trn:` N x 1 tensor (pytorch's array)
- `k_trn:` N x K tensor
- `x_trn:` N x n tensor

The rows of `u_trn,k_trn,x_trn` correspond to three trajectories (with u corresponding to the "input"). Each time I iterate over the loader (which can be done, e.g. with a loop `for u,k,x in loader:`), I get a batch of 20 rows from u_trn, 20 rows of k_trn, and 20 rows of x_trn. These rows are selected with a uniform probability, without replacement.

The catch is that I would like to sample these rows with a **non-uniform** probability. In particular: denote S = (1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/N). I would like for the loader to select the jth row with probability 1/(S*j).

After looking at [the relevant doumentation,](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) I suspect that this can be done by messing with either the `sampler` or `batch_sampler` keyword arguments when initializing the `DataLoader` object, but I'm having trouble parsing the documentation well enough to implement the behavior that I'm looking for.

I'd appreciate any help with this. I've tried to keep my question brief; please let me know if I've left out any relevant information.

---

Followup: with the help of Shai's answer, I've gotten things to work properly. Here's a quick script that I used to test this out and make sure that everything was working as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset, WeightedRandomSampler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
x = np.zeros((N,2))
x[:,0] = 1 + np.arange(N)
data = TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(x))

weights = [1/j for j in range(1, N+1)]  # my weights
sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(weights, 10000, replacement=True)
loader = DataLoader(data, batch_size=20, sampler=sampler)
sums = []

for y, in loader:
    for k in range(len(y)):
        sums.append(np.sum(y[k].numpy()))

h = plt.hist(sums, bins = N)
a = h[0][0]
plt.plot([a/(n+1) for n in range(N)], lw = 3)
```

And the resulting plot:

[image]

Note that weights are automatically normalized, so there is no need to divide by the sum S. Note also that there is no need for `shuffle=True` in the loader; the sampler takes care of the randomization on its own.

Comment: I'll be away from my computer for the next few hours, so if I don't respond to your comment, that's why. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use [`WeightedRandomSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.WeightedRandomSampler)?

```py
weights = [1./(S*j) for j in range(1, N+1)]  # your weights
sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(weights, replacement=True)
loader = DataLoader(data, batch_size=20, sampler=sampler)
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should be using `sampler` or `batch_sampler`, and I was thrown off by the fact that there was no requirement for the weights to have the same size as the `data` input. I'll give this a shot when I get the chance and see if it works as expected.

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much. A mild correction to you answer: `WeightedRandomSampler` has a mandatory second argument `num_samples`, which is the total (maximum) number of samples that can be generated from the sampler.